# How to test a request parameter with value on a XML document

Tags: xml, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have a little problem when I try to make a test to sort my data on a JSP page, it's a basic example with library core and XML.

In page `index.jsp` the user choose the author of the book.
In page `res.jsp` I try to select the book of the author selected in `index.jsp` **but the code between `<c:if test="....>...</c:if>` is ignored.**

The code of **index.jsp**:

```
<form method="get" action="res.jsp">  
    <select name="combo1"> 
        <option value="atlas">atlas </option>
        <option value="echchadi">echchadi </option>
        <option value="fertat">fertat </option>
        <option value="bouarifi">bouarifi </option>
    </select>  <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

code of **res.jsp**:

```
 <c:import url="books.xml" var="documentXML"/>
    <%--On parse le document récupérer --%>
    <x:parse doc="${documentXML}" var="doc"/>
    <c:set value="${param.combo1}" var="prof"/>
    <c:out value="${prof}"/>
    <x:forEach select="$doc/books/book" var="naw">            
        <x:set select="$naw/author" var="author"/>
        <x:if select="$author eq $prof">
            <x:out select="$naw/title"/>
            <x:out select="$naw/author"/>
        </x:if>
    </x:forEach>
```

Any idea why the mentioned code is ignored?

Comment: What is the 'x' prefix? You mentioned '<c:if>' but presented '<x:if>'

Comment: at the first time i tried to use if wich is in the core library x refer to the if in the xml library, at the first time i trief to do my test with <c:if ..> but it didn't work, at the seconde time i tried with <x:if> it didn't work too

Comment: So, it doesn't enter the code inside the `<c:if>` block? I haven't written any JSP for some time now, but shouldn't it be `${author eq prof}`?

Comment: it doesn't work too i tried different way to compare i had a message that says that select in tag <x:if> does not accept any EL

Comment: You did try something like `<c:if test="${author == prof}">...</c:if>`? Does your `<c:out value="${prof}">` works fine and prints the value?

Comment: the c:out value="${prof}"> it works, and yes i have tried <c:if test="${author == prof}">...</c:if>

Comment: And are you sure that 'author' and 'prof' objects supposed to be equal?

Comment: yes, because the author at the combolist are the same in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the XML library, but I would expect `<c:if test="${author eq prof}">` to work.

If not, it seems likely to me that they're never equal. Maybe the authors in the XML file have capital letters or something. I'd try outputting the value of `author` in each iteration, in that case... just to be sure that what the XML library is reading is what you're expecting.